# Compiling and linking multiple c++ projects into one big c++ project

Tags: c++, compilation, packaging, dynamic-linking

> I want to use multiple existing projects as a part of my C++ project.

For example boost or berkeley db:

In boost documentation there are several ways written.
Using headers or building and linking.

> There is an automated script for BerkeleyDb here that can be used for bitcoin/dash:

[Install db4](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/install_db4.sh)

But I can see a

> boost.mk

file which is a makefile for install boost into the Dash project:

[Boost mk as a package in Dash project](https://github.com/dashpay/dash/blob/master/depends/packages/boost.mk)

I want to do the same for the openDHT project given here:

[openDHT C++](https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/opendht)

I don't want specific instructions for this specific procedure, but I would like to know the steps involved in using an open source project like boost source code and reaching boost.mk step finally.

Any help is appreciated.

I use linux(Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: Why do you need to compile the other projects from source code? Can you not just use them as external libraries?

Comment: There is plenty of documentation for that online. For example: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html and https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/writing-makefiles/ - I'd recommend doing a bit more research.

Comment: @Galik Yes I can use them as external libraries as well, but in order to learn I want to do it once myself.